# Electric Field inside a long cylinder with uniform surface charge density

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Why is the field inside a uniformly charged long hollow cylinder zero?

Comment: Voting to reopen.  Posting answers to your own questions is [explicitly encouraged by SE policy,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and there's even a button on the "New Question" page that allows you to post them simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Consider our cylinder to be of radius $b$. Now construct another cylinder coaxial to the original one with radius $r<b$. If we calculate the flux through this cylinder we get
$$\oint\vec E\cdot d\vec a=\frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0}=0\tag{01}$$

From symmetry we can say that the field must be radial in direction thus we can pull out electric field from the integral.
But since the radius of the constructed cylinder is arbitrary we see that within the original cylinder $E=0$.

Comment: @Frobenius while asking a question there is an option to answer it on your own which is promoted by stackexchange itself, please look into it for more as to why doing this not wrong.

Comment: I edit your answer in order to retract my downvote. I retracted my downvote from your question too although I don't agree to post answers to our own questions simultaneously  as explicitly encouraged by SE policy.